# Importing a file in Access which contains "." in it's name using VBA

Tags: ms-access, import, vba

I am trying to import a csv file into my access database. It reads like this:
"Vol.2016.Aug.23.csv"

When I try to import this using docmd, it gives me an error that it cannot import the file. I figured out the problem that it cannot identify the file as a csv because of the multiple "."

However, I would be getting files named in such a way which I need to import. Is there any way to go about this?

Please help!

Here's my code:

```
fileName = "Vol." & Year(Date) & "." & MonthName(Month(Date), True) & "." & Day(Date) &  ".csv"

filePath = "C:\Users\House\Desktop\"

DoCmd.TransferText Transfertype:=acImportDelim, TableName:="Table1", fileName:=filePath + fileName, HasFieldNames:=True
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: _____fileName = "Vol." & Year(Date) & "." & MonthName(Month(Date), True) & "." & Day(Date) '&  ".csv"

______filePath = "C:\Users\House\Desktop\"


_____DoCmd.TransferText Transfertype:=acImportDelim, TableName:="Table1", fileName:=filePath + fileName, HasFieldNames:=True

Comment: Please update the code in the question, and use Code formatting.

Comment: Just updated my code in the question! Sorry about that

Comment: @Shreyans next time also please use the code formatting option (I have edited your post so that the code is formatted *as code*). This makes it much easier to read & understand what you are doing.

Comment: Does it work if you uncomment the `&  ".csv"` part?

Comment: @Comintern good catch! Yes I'd suspect right now it's getting a file of type `.23`...

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I would surely do that next time. Apologies

Comment: No it does not work even if I uncomment that part out! I've updated my code with the ".csv" uncommented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following solution a try.

Instead of trying to deal with the periods being present in the filename, I wrote a script to *temporarily* rename the file name. Basically I replace `.` with `_` to get around the import issue.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportTableWithPeriod()
    Dim fso             As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim f               As Object
    Dim FolderName      As String
    Dim Filename        As String
    Dim TempFilepath    As String
    Dim OrigFilePath    As String
    Dim TempFileName    As String
    Dim tempFolderPath  As String

    Filename = "Vol." & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "." & _
                Format(Now(), "MMM") & "." & _
                Format(Now(), "d") & ".csv"

    FolderName = "C:\Users\House\Desktop\"

    'Build string for replacement names
    'Basically I've replaced the periods with underscores
    TempFileName = Replace(Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 4), ".", "-") & ".csv"
    TempFilepath = FolderName & TempFileName

    OrigFilePath = FolderName & Filename
    Set f = fso.getFile(OrigFilePath)

    'rename the file temporarily
    f.Name = TempFileName

    'Import the file with the renamed instance
    DoCmd.TransferText Transfertype:=acImportDelim, TableName:="Table1", Filename:=TempFilepath, HasFieldNames:=True

    'Put the name back as it was
    f.Name = Filename

    'Clean up
    set fso = nothing
    set f = nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay - this should work for you

I tested on my system and confirmed that your DoCmd call probably uses old MS-ACcess code base requirements and is failing on the "." and any other special chars in the filename - probably something hardcoded to look for the first dot in filename in order to figure out the extension

> Solution is to use Short Filenames

**Add this to top of your module**

```
' Borrowed code from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175512

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32" _
      Alias "GetShortPathNameA" (ByVal lpszLongPath As String, _
      ByVal lpszShortPath As String, ByVal cchBuffer As Long) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32" _
      Alias "GetShortPathNameA" (ByVal lpszLongPath As String, _
      ByVal lpszShortPath As String, ByVal cchBuffer As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Function GetShortName(ByVal sLongFileName As String) As String
    Dim lRetVal As Long, sShortPathName As String, iLen As Integer
    'Set up buffer area for API function call return
    sShortPathName = Space(255)
    iLen = Len(sShortPathName)

    'Call the function
    lRetVal = GetShortPathName(sLongFileName, sShortPathName, iLen)
    'Strip away unwanted characters.
    GetShortName = Left(sShortPathName, lRetVal)
End Function
```

**Then modify your code to convert your filename to Short version**

```
Dim filename As String
Dim filePath As String

Dim csvFile As String

filename = "Vol." & Year(Date) & "." & MonthName(Month(Date), True) & "." & Day(Date) & ".csv"

filePath = "C:\Users\House\Desktop\"

' Convert to Short Filename to work with old MS-Access code base
csvFile = GetShortName(filePath & filename)
Debug.Print csvFile

DoCmd.TransferText Transfertype:=acImportDelim, TableName:="Table1", filename:=csvFile, HasFieldNames:=True
```

Comment: this works perfectly. I upvoted your answer because it's the cleanest one that doesn't involve file renaming or temporary files. Thanks a lot!